# retrieve information after img tag using jsoup

Tags: html, jsoup

I'd like to retrieve some content in the html code using jsoup

```
  <td valign="top" align="middle" class="text" align="center">
   <img border="1" alt="board4" src="/graphics/associatn/12_ngo_soo_lin.jpg" width="80" height="101"><br>
   <b>吴斯仁</b><br>一丰有限公司
  </td>
```

I managed to retrieve the image by using:

```
Element image = doc.select("td.text img").get(c);
String url = image.absUrl("src");
Log.d("image", url);
```

How do i retrieve the text

```
<br><b>吴斯仁</b><br>一丰有限公司
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need a.) the text or b.) the text incl. html tags?

a.) `String text = doc.select("td").text();`

b.) `String text = doc.select("td > img ~ *").toString();`

Comment: b retrieves the <br> and <b> tags as well. how do i get rid of them?

Comment: If you don't need these tags, you can use a.) or replace `toString()` in b.) with `text()`.